# SQL - Trouble using COUNT query

Tags: mysql, sql

Good day again to all SQL guru here :)

I have a problem querying my table using COUNT.

This is the data inside of the table (tblstudentoffense)

[image]

And this is the RESULT that I want (Let's say that there is a new column after the offenseType that will count the Stealing and Gaming Offense

[image]

Is this possible? If possible kindly add an explanation with your provided code. Thanks :)

Comment: Please read [postgresql-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) then **[edit]** your question and provide the missing information.

Comment: What sort of data is hiding behind the blacked out squares?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i'm using MySQL by phpMyAdmin

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just hide the name of the owner just a respect... you can see the Student ID all data are the same but difference offenseType.

Comment: Your expected output does not make sense.  _Which_ value of `offenseFN` should be displayed for a given combination of `studentID` and `offenseType`?

Comment: Rather than images, you should paste the data as text and replace the real names with mock ones. Thus we could see which of the four offenseLN, which of the four offenseFN, and which of the four offenseMN for 'stealing' you want to show in your results (the choice of which you hopefully would explain, too).

Answer (score 1):

Using subquery to get count and concatenate count with main select statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT OffenseType + ' ' + CAST(B.Cnt AS VARCHAR) ,  
Othercolumn1,Othercolumn2
FROM Your_tableName A
JOIN 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) Cnt , StudentId
  FROM Your_tableName
  GROUP BY StudentId 
) B ON B.StudentId = A.StudentId
```

Comment: This doesn't match the expected output.

Comment: I'll try this one later. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `CONCAT_WS()`.The `CONCAT_WS()` function is used to join two or more strings with a separator.

> Note: **offensetypeCount** is an new column having expected output.

```
SELECT *,CONCAT_WS(' ',offensetype,count(offenseType) AS offensetypeCount FROM tblstudentoffense GROUP BY offensetype;
```

Comment: Is * in select possible when you have only offensetype field in groupby?

Comment: I don't think the fields which are not in group by cannot be fetched using select clause

Comment: @Mark did you try this.

Comment: I'll try this one too later. Thanks for the reply. (I'm busy at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
 WITH SRC AS  
    (SELECT 'STEALING' OFFENSETYPE,'1' STUDENTID FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
     SELECT 'STEALING' OFFENSETYPE,'1' STUDENTID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'STEALING' OFFENSETYPE,'1' STUDENTID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'STEALING' OFFENSETYPE,'1' STUDENTID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
     SELECT 'GAMING' OFFENSETYPE,'1' STUDENTID FROM DUAL UNION ALL)  
     SELECT OFFENSETYPE,STUDENTID,COUNT(*) FROM SRC GROUP BY OFFENSETYPE,STUDENTID;
```

Comment: I'll try this too later. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
SELECT CONCAT(offensetype, ' ', COUNT(offensetype)) AS offenseType, 
       studentid, 
       offenseln, 
       offensefn, 
       offensemn, 
       offensesuffixname 
FROM   tblstudentoffense
GROUP  BY offensetype, 
          studentid, 
          offenseln, 
          offensefn, 
          offensemn, 
          offensesuffixname;
```

I've created a sample at this link http://rextester.com/WZGW41761.

Comment: I'll try this one too later. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: based on your example. Your code is fit on result that I want :-) to all who gave their answers I will test them all but for now I will use Trung Duong code since I understand a little of his code :-) Thanks